# cookies are blocked from keycloak localhost to my application localhost, cecause path was not an exact match or a superdirectory or request url path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

I have a keycloak server running in localhost:8080 and a web app server written in ASP.NET MVC 4.7 running in https:localhost:44337,

the application uses the keycloak to authenticate and login, and after succesful login it should redirect to https:localhost:44337/home,
from dev tools i see that Sessions are passed correctly but it is blocked because "This cookie was blocked because its path was not an exact match for or a superdirectory of the request url's path".
Is this maybe because I am testing in localhost with different port? is this samesite issue?

[image]

How can I resolve this while developing locally and I dont have a domain?
It seems like by googling this error does not come out.